# Copy cells from source workbook to variable rows in destination workbook based on a variable from source workbook

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I copy adjacent cells (b1 - g1) from a source workbook (NEW RCA TUNE 23 v2) to a destination workbook (RCA NUMBER LOG) in a specified row dictated by a variable row number (Val) generated in the source workbook.

However, when I change the variable in the source workbook, and write to that new row in the destination workbook, it also overwrites any previous rows information with the latest information.

```vb
Sub vba_copy_to_NumberLog()
Dim Val As Integer
Val = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Value
Workbooks("NEW RCA JUNE 23 v2").Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("b1", "g1").Copy _
  Workbooks("RCA NUMBER LOG").Worksheets("RCA Log").Range("c" & Val, "h" & Val)
End Sub
```

Comment: With "any previous rows information", do you mean it overwrites `.Range("D" & Val,"G" & Val)` as well? Because that's included in your copy so that makes sense. You'd be better off assigning the value separately, i.e. B1=>"CVal", G1 => "HVal".

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Sub vba_copy_to_NumberLog()

    Dim Val As Long
    Dim wbNRJUN As Workbook, wbRNL As Workbook
    Dim wsSht3 As Worksheet, wsRL As Worksheet

    Set wbNRJUN = Workbooks("NEW RCA JUNE 23 v2")
    Set wbRNL = Workbooks("RCA NUMBER LOG")
    Set wsSht3 = wbNRJUN.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Set wsRL = wbRNL.Worksheets("RCA Log")

    Val = wsSht3.Range("A1").Value
    wsSht3.Range("B1", "G1").Copy _
        wsRL.Range("C" & Val, "H" & Val)
    
End Sub
```